# Zusammengesetzte Substantive

Tags: history, spelling, compound

Aus *Programmieren in C*  von Kerninghan, Ritchie (deutsche Ausgabe von 1983) :

> In C sind die prinzipiellen Daten Objekte Zeichen, Zahlenwerte mit verschiedenem Speicherbedarf und Gleitkomma Zahlen.

Das ist nur ein Beispiel von vielen, es wirkt, als hätten die Übersetzer das Englische eins zu eins, ohne Rücksicht auf Verluste ins Deutsche übersetzt und dabei komplett ignoriert, dass manche Wörter einfach zusammengehören.
Meine Frage ist nicht, ob das so korrekt ist, weil ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass das so falsch ist, teilweise sogar Information verloren geht, sondern ich frage mich, ob das zum Zeitpunkt der Übersetzung vielleicht so üblich war? Falls nicht, wundert es mich, dass das kein Korrekturleser bemängelt hat.

Comment: Vermutlich konnte weder der Übersetzer noch der Lektor 1983 etwas mit C anfangen ;)

Comment: Aber doch wohl mit Deutsch?

Comment: Ich glaube einfach, dass es aus der Zeit in diesem Bereich schlechte Übersetzungen gibt. Ich glaube, mir ist das auch in diesem Bereich in den 80ern zum ersten Mal aufgefallen. Ich habe den Text deshalb zunächst gar nicht verstanden. Gute Beobachtung!

Comment: Can you give the chapter and section, where this quote is from, so that we can look up the original text.

Comment: It's right from the beginning, chapter 0, third page in the german version. But I think it's pretty clear how it will look in englisch.

Comment: (…) zusammengesetzte Wörter schreiben sich entweder zusammen oder mit Bindestrich, aber niemals getrennt, wie es im Englischen gebräuchlich ist. Bindestriche werden (…) nur verwendet, um Unklarheiten zu vermeiden (…), die einzelnen Bestandteile eines Kompositums hervorzuheben (…) oder um eine bessere Lesbarkeit zu gewährleisten (…). (…) auch englische Ausdrücke [werden] in der deutschen Sprache entweder zusammengeschrieben oder mit Bindestrich verbunden(…) **Diese Regel wird in unserem Sprachraum leider sehr häufig nicht eingehalten.** http://www.global-translations.ch/de/blog/komposita

Comment: "ob das zum Zeitpunkt der Übersetzung vielleicht so üblich war"? Nein, auch damals war es nicht üblich. _In der deutschen Sprache werden Komposita immer zusammengeschrieben. Eine Alternative ist die Trennung der einzelnen Kompositumsbestandteile voneinander mit Bindestrich. Ein Leerzeichen in einem Kompositum ist in jedem Fall unzulässig._ [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)#Rechtschreibung)

Answer (score 5):

Man muss den genauen englischen Wortlaut kennen, um beurteilen zu können, ob dem Übersetzer die Programmiersprache geläufig sein musste oder nicht, um korrekt zu übersetzen. Die 1. Auflage von "The C Programming Language" aus dem Jahr 1978 scheint im Netz nicht verfügbar zu sein, nur die offenbar gründlich umgearbeitete zweite. Dort findet sich unter 2.2 (Seite 35) folgender Absatz:

```
There are only a few basic data types in C: 
char   – a single byte, capable of holding one character in the local character set 
int    – an integer, typically reflecting the natural size of integers on the host machine 
float  – single-precision floating point 
double – double-precision floating point
```

Das war nicht die Vorlage der fraglichen Übersetzung, wie @Benjoyo festgestellt hat, doch es zeigt ganz allgemein, dass das Englische die entsprechende Struktur hat, um nicht verbundenen Komposita ihre Bedeutung eindeutig zuzuschreiben, das Deutsche hingegen nicht. Ich (als C-Analphabet) habe den deutschen Beispielsatz beim ersten Hinschauen so gelesen:

> In C sind die prinzipiellen Daten Objekte, Zeichen, Zahlenwerte mit
>   verschiedenem Speicherbedarf und Gleitkomma-Zahlen.

Es hätte im ersten Teil des Satzes theoretisch ein Bindestrich oder ein Komma fehlen können, allerdings weist der fehlende Bindestrich in "Gleitkomma Zahlen" auf Ersteres hin. Es ist nicht Aufgabe des Lesers, herauszufinden, welcher Fehler des Autors oder Übersetzers der wahrscheinlichere ist, und ein Text führt sich selbst ad absurdum, wenn er vom Leser erwartet, ohnehin schon zu wissen, was er sagen will, weil die Fehler dann nicht mehr ins Gewicht fallen.

Mein Blick in die (populäre) deutschsprachige Computerliteratur der 80er-Jahre ist leider alles andere als repräsentativ, da ich für diese Antwort nur zwei Quellen zur Verfügung habe. Anhand dieser Quellen fällt der Befund über die Tendenz, unverbundene englische Komposita 1:1 ins Deutsche zu übernehmen, vor allem Fach- bzw. stehende Begriffe, ziemlich eindeutig aus:

1. H.P. Blomeyer-Bartenstein, Personal Computer – das intelligente Werkzeug für jedermann, Haar b. München: Markt&Technik 1983:

   > Personal Computer
   >   Personal Computer System

   hingegen:

   > Mehrbenutzer-(Multi-User)System
   >   Personal Computer-System
   >   Computerhardware
   >   Gleitkommazahldarstellung
   >   Mailing-List
   >   Hard-Disk
   >   etc.

Eine oberflächliche Durchsicht dieses Buches zeigt, dass die heute grassierende Tendenz zum unverbundenen deutschen Kompositum ("Deppen Leerzeichen") nicht festzustellen ist, im Gegenteil, der Autor versucht, die englischen Fachbegriffe möglichst "sauber" ins Deutsche zu übertragen und setzt Bindestriche, wo sie heute nicht mehr üblich sind.

2. Ein Papierausdruck eines C-Kurses von Christoph Resele aus den 80er- oder frühen 90er-Jahren, der noch als Teletext (!) im ORF verfügbar war, zeigt ein ähnliches Bild:

   > End-of-File Kennung

   hingegen:

   > C-Kurs
   >   PC-Benutzer
   >   Whitespace-Zeichen
   >   float-Variable
   >   ASCII-Code
   >   etc.

Während Blomeyer-Bartenstein zusammengesetzte Begriffe häufig ohne Bindestrich zusammenzieht, verwendet Resele fast ausschließlich Bindestriche. Soweit ich das beurteilen kann, lässt er Zusammensetzungen nur dann unverbunden, wenn, wie bei End-of-File Kennung, dabei unterschiedliche Aussagearten zusammenstoßen.

Als zusätzliche Quelle aus den 70er-Jahren kann ich noch Walter Grafendorfers *Einführung in die Datenverarbeitung für Informatiker* heranziehen (Würzburg, Wien: Physica 1977). Hier findet sich kein einziger unverbunden zusammengesetzter Begriff.

Selbst wenn der Begriff "Datenobjekt" im Deutschen noch nicht eingeführt war, existierten bereits genügend Begriffe, die als Modell für eine unmissverständliche deutsche Kompositabildung im Fachbereich der Informatik herangezogen werden konnten, eine entsprechende sprachliche Kompetenz vorausgesetzt. Die Übersetzer Axel-Tobias Schreiner und Ernst Janich waren in dieser Hinsicht leider ihrer Zeit voraus, denn wie die drei anderen Texte zeigen, war das Bewusstsein einer Transposition von der einen in die andere Sprache – und der entsprechenden spezifischen sprachlichen Voraussetzungen – in dieser Zeit durchaus und m.E. in sehr viel höherem Maß vorhanden als heute.

Comment: Man könnte das zwar grammatikalisch auf eine mangelhafte Zeichensetzung zurückführen, aber so, wie Du vorschlägst funktioniert das nicht. Es sind im genannten Beispiel die  "Datenobjekte" gemeint, nicht "Daten, die auch Objekte sein können". Nun gab es aber 1983 ein "Datenobjekt" noch so gut wie nicht (siehe auch mein Ngram). Es scheint also doch eher ein Problem der mangelhaften Kompositabildung zu sein, wie es auch der OP in seiner Frage formuliert hatte.

Comment: Der Absatz, den du da hast, ist nicht der gesuchte. Der ist in der deutschen Version genauso. Ich meine Kapitel 0, ca. Seite 3. Aber das ganze zieht sich eh durch das komplette Buch.

Comment: @Takkat Natürlich sind Datenobjekte gemeint, aber ich habe – aufgrund der Worttrennung – den Satz eben zuerst so gelesen wie angegeben. Es ist die Aufgabe eines Autors oder Übersetzers, eine Aussage nach den Regeln der Sprache so zu gestalten, dass der Leser nicht erraten muss, was er gemeint hat, das ist eine grundsätzliche Forderung funktionierender Kommunikation. Gerade dann, wenn ein Begriff im Deutschen noch nicht eingeführt ist, wäre das die Chance, ihn diesem Prinzip folgend zu prägen und nicht irgendwie. Dass das auch versucht worden ist, zeigen m.E. meine beiden Beispiele.

Comment: @Benjoyo Finde ich in diesem PDF leider nicht - http://www.google.at/url?q=http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf&sa=U&ei=E5X9VP7EKMWyUdrYgbgK&ved=0CBMQFjAA&sig2=qykdzYxn_Nb9JDDFW4-sUA&usg=AFQjCNFuNyeMGB-rr3ob9hn4QWDHierK9A - wahrscheinlich, weil die Übersetzung von der ersten Auflage ausgeht.

Comment: Stimmt, Kapitel 0 fehlt einfach.

Answer (score 2):

Vermutlich waren die Komposita, die uns heute so selbstverständlich erscheinen, im Jahr 1983 noch kaum gebräuchlich, so dass weder der Übersetzer noch der Lektor diese kannten.

[image]
<sup>[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Datenobjekt%2CGleitkommazahlen&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDatenobjekt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGleitkommazahlen%3B%2Cc0)</sup>

Comment: Inwiefern soll das relevant sein?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz na, es erkärt schon, warum man diese Wörter in den frühen 80er Jahren noch nicht kannte. Kaum ein Übersetzer war wohl auch Informatiker, aber manche Übersetzer haben ihren Job so gut gemacht, dass die von ihnen erfundenen Begriffe heute allgemeiner Sprachgebrauch geworden sind.

Comment: Hier sind nicht Wörter unbekannt sondern die Regeln wie man Wörter bildet. Viel eher konnte der Übersetzer C aber nicht Deutsch auf dem Niveau mittlerer Reife. Ich glaube nicht, dass man mit alternativen Substantiven in dieser Konstellation einen gültigen Satz bauen kann. "In X sind die prinzipiellen M N O, P mit verschiedenem Q und R S.", mit beliebigen Substantiven M-S in entsprechender Ein-/Mehrzahl und Kasus.

Comment: @userunknown: nun geht es in der Frage aber nicht darum, was richtig oder falsch ist, denn das schließt der OP eindeutig aus, sondern **warum** das so gewesen sein könnte. Mehr, als dass es 1983 ein Problem der noch nicht existierenden Fachterminologie war, fällt mir nicht ein. Du kannst gerne eine andere These versuchen. Einfach nur ein "schlechter Übersetzer" wäre aber nicht wirklich ein Thema für German Language, oder?

Comment: *Programmieren in C* ist von Axel-Tobias Schreiner übersetzt worden.
Schreiner war Informatik-Dozent und eben kein gelernter Übersetzer;
insofern steht außer Frage, daß die idiosynkratische Orthographie
dieses Buches nicht auf mangelnde Fachkenntnisse, sondern auf
mangelnde Orthographiekenntnisse (oder einen persönlichen Spleen)
zurückzuführen ist. Wieso der Korrektor das hat durchgehen lassen,
ist eine gute Frage – vielleicht hat der Verlag den Korrektor auch
komplett eingespart.

Comment: @Uwe: umso schlimmer... ;)

Comment: @Takkat: Was macht man, wenn es keine etablierte Fachterminologie gibt? Entweder man übernimmt die engl. Fachtermini, oder man versucht deutsche Ersatzbegriffe zu schaffen und weist bei der ersten Verwendung auf den Originalbegriff hin. Wörtliche Übersetzung ist in vielen Fällen ein probates Mittel und wurde hier auch gewählt, aber die dt. Grammatik ist dennoch anzuwenden - das ist der einfachste Teil bei diesem Unterfangen und hat mit dem speziellen Fach nichts zu tun.